# App is working nice on flash builder, but when export it, It doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

I made a action script desktop app, when I run/debug inside flash builder, everything works fine, but when I export a release build, the released app opens and instantly closes. No errors are thrown and It doesn't keep opened in background. My project doesn't have errors, neither warnings. I tried exporting as AIR package, native installer and app with captive runtime, all of them failed.

I'm using Starling. Hints will be nice too!

INFO.: Win 7 64bit, Flash Builder 4.7, no process running in background. The process opens and closes.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import starling.core.Starling;
    import flash.events.Event;

    [SWF(frameRate="30", width="240", height="160", backgroundColor="0x222222")]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var myStarling:Starling;
        public static var debugSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

        public function Main()
        {   
            myStarling = new Starling(Game, stage);
            myStarling.antiAliasing = 1;
            myStarling.showStats = true;

            stage.stage3Ds[0].addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, onContextCreated);
        }

        private function onContextCreated(e:Event):void{
            myStarling.start();
            addChild(debugSprite);
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Also tested with this `Main.as`:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import starling.core.Starling;

    [SWF(frameRate="30", width="240", height="160", backgroundColor="0x222222")]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var myStarling:Starling;

        public function Main()
        {   
            myStarling = new Starling(Game, stage);
            myStarling.antiAliasing = 4;
            myStarling.showStats = true;
            myStarling.start();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using, It looks like Windows, but is it 32 bit or 64 bit? Which Flash Builder version? Have you checked your running processes via `CTRL+ALT+DELETE -> Task Manager` to see if the executable is running but not visible? You tagged `starling-framework`, did you call `Starling.start()` in the Starling init process?

Comment: @JoãoPauloOliveiraFernandes Just a simple question : why the `Main.exe` has a different date than other files ?

Comment: good question! dont know...

Comment: very crazy date, btw

Comment: Also, why your `Main` requests `stage` in constructor? It might not be available in the exported package.

Comment: Try to delete .exe and export release build again. EXE appears with the same date?

Comment: @Vesper I don't know, but if I don't pass it here `new Starling(Game, stage);`, the program throw me an error. @subdan I deleted and exported again. Same date...

Comment: I'll try export without the `Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE` event and pass start() to the constructor.

Comment: Did'nt work, but still passing stage on Startling(). Here is a detailed image of Main.exe dates http://s15.postimg.org/eon9uofdn/date.png

Comment: Try to rename your project, or create a new one with the same code and try again, and if there is a possibility, could you share your project to test it may be someone here could find the real origin of your problem ?

Comment: Project link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxKv92dlk8E8engxVFVtQ2FyNnM&usp=sharing

Comment: I tested your code using FB 4.5 with Flex 4.6 for AIR 3.1 and it's working fine, take a look [here](http://www.image-share.com/igif-2865-55.html).

Comment: ... And you can download the project and its install from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/8a2hjjc6d8bnm8c/test01.zip).

Comment: Well, something came to my head now. I'm using the 60 days trial of Flash Builder. That would be a problem?

Comment: let me test your project first..

Comment: I could export with your project... What you have set?